# Get UserName and Password in WinRT?

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-authentication

I have created a sample application in Windows 8 I need username and password of logged in user of Windows to authenticate him/ her in the application. I know that we can use `Environment.CurrentUser` in Old desktop application how can i get User Info for authentication purpose in Windows 8 Metro Application?

Comment: I have looked into that but it doesn't given me login id for the user its gives me just the user name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current user name but never the password.

To make your scenario work your app needs to select the enterpriseAuthentication capability and then you should be able to use `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` from within your app